# Stripe undefined method `create' for #<Stripe::ListObject:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm trying to allow a user to add a credit card in my app using Stripe. When i call the code below (which is from the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card), I get the error below.

Are the docs out of date or am i doing something wrong?

`@card = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_account.stripe_id).cards.create(:card => params[:stripeToken])`

```
undefined method `create' for #<Stripe::ListObject:...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for creating a card was added in version 1.8.4 of the Stripe gem. You'll need to make sure you're using that version or newer, otherwise you'll see that error.

Comment: I had version 1.8.3 installed because I copied the gemfile line from here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails. This guide should be updated to not include the reference to github.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by replacing: gem "stripe" in my gemfile with: gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby', and then running bundle. It was working fine, and then out of nowhere threw this error, but updating seemed to fix it.